# Grape Vine identify disease please

Tags: diseases, grape-vine, discoloration

Can anyone help me to identify  what is wrong with my Muscat Vine?

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Leaf Picture] | [image: Leaf Picture] |

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider the [Ontario IPM sheet related to Nitrogen deficiency](http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/IPM/english/grapes/plant-nutrition/nitrogen.html). In particular this mentions that cool weather or very dry conditions can cause the vines to fail to benefit from N in the soil. The N is there so there is no need to increase levels, just wait for conditions to change. The yellowing of leaves, with red in the petioles and shoots as indicated in your image would be consistent with low N. Clearly your plants are quite advanced for the season compared to Ontario, so perhaps you are in a favourable climate or greenhouse situation?

Comment: Climate is Middle East, with most of the last week being about 41c/ 106f,  with drip irrigation.   So I will hit it with some fertilizer right away, hopefully that helps.